# QueryString to Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table tblProfile, which contains fields with Id, Name, Address. I have 2 aspx page, which are Home.aspx and Here.aspx. On my Home.aspx I have used this code to pass the Id in my Here.aspx:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Here.aspx?id={0}" 
            Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="Medium" >Click here</asp:HyperLink>
```

In code behind Home.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string bID = Request.QueryString["Id"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
    {
        Response.Redirect("Here.aspx?", true);
    }
    ViewState["Id"] = Id;
    link.NavigateUrl = String.Format(link.NavigateUrl, Id);

}
```

I don't have any problem with passing the Id to url in 2nd page. But what I want right now is, on my Here.aspx, I have 3 textboxes which supposed to be filled by the Id, Name and Address of the certain Id that passed from the Home.aspx. Tried many but had no luck at all. Any help would be appreciated. By the way, I'm using asp.net with c#.

Comment: how do you want to load name and address in your `Here.aspx` page? By retrieving from database or from `Home.aspx` page?

Comment: what you have tried write the code and let us know what problem you have while trying that...

Comment: Do you want to send the Name,address to Here.aspx,If so,try it like this <asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Here.aspx?id={0}&Name={1}&Address={2}"             Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="Medium" >Click here</asp:HyperLink>

Comment: @sarwar026 - I'm retrieving datas from my database not from Home.aspx. Id is working now, as I used this code behind page load on my Here.aspx txtid.Text = Request.QueryString["id"]; but Name and Address, no idea at all. Thanks again for replying

Comment: @MahaSwetha - I'm retrieving datas from my database not from Home.aspx. Id is working now, as I used this code behind page load on my Here.aspx txtid.Text = Request.QueryString["id"]; but Name and Address, no idea at all. Thanks again for replying

Answer (score 1):

We are having two solution for it

Solution 1 : User Previous page property in asp.net so that you no need to pass ID. i.e.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Find the name on the previous page
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("txtNameText");

        if (txt != null)
            txtName.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(txt.Text);
        else
            txtName.Text = "[Name Not available]";
    }
```

Solution 2 : Get ID from query string and get Data by ID in assign on text box text property.i.e.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get value from query string
            string profileID = Request.QueryString["Id"];

            // Fetch data from database by ID
            DataTable dt = FetchEmployeeDataByID(ProfileID);

            txtName.text = dt.rows[0]["Name"].tostring();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your reply on comments, I suggest to do the following:

1. Load your data in `Here.aspx` back-end (.cs file) by the `Id` that you retrieve from query string
2. Show the loaded data into your desired textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name and address by retrieving the profile data from the database using the Id from the query string as the key.

So in your Here.aspx's code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string profileID = Request.QueryString["Id"];
    // Retrive profile in your db..
    var profile = Profiles.Get(p => p.ProfileID == profileID);

    // Populate the textboxes
    txtId.Text = profileID;
    txtName.Text = profile.Name;
    txtAddress.Text = profile.Address;
}
```